# Laravel Change Connection Dynamically

Tags: php, database, laravel, connection

How to change laravel's connection form controller but the connection information stored at database like database manager, my example :

I have a databases information on my database :

```
id, driver, database_name, username, password, host
```

so at my controller just call :

```
$connection = Database::find( 1 );
$users = new Users();
$users->setConnection( [
    'driver' => $connection->driver,
    'host' => $connection->host,
    'username' => $connection->username,
    'password' => $connection->password
] );
$users = $users->get();
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I will go for a helper here. Let's create one in `app/Helpers/DatabaseConnection.php`.

```
namespace App\Helpers;
use Config;
use DB;

class DatabaseConnection
{
    public static function setConnection($params)
    {
        config(['database.connections.onthefly' => [
            'driver' => $params->driver,
            'host' => $params->host,
            'username' => $params->username,
            'password' => $params->password
        ]]);

        return DB::connection('onthefly');
    }
}
```

And now somewhere in controller we try

```
use App\Helpers\DatabaseConnection;
... 

$params = Database::find( 1 );
$connection = DatabaseConnection::setConnection($params);
$users = $connection->select(...);
```

**Note: Not tested. I hope it works or simply guide you**

More info:

- Using multi database: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database#read-and-write-connections
- Setting configurations on the fly: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/configuration#accessing-configuration-values

Comment: Yes this is working, thank you, this is what i am looking for.

Comment: how do u choose table name?

Comment: I imagine life without this your solution. Great work. Thanks. life saver.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, EddyTheDove, I am using your solution which is great :) just to know how to select table name I am putting this

```
namespace App\Helpers;
use Config;
use DB;

class DatabaseConnection
{
    public static function setConnection($params)
    {
        config(['database.connections.onthefly' => [
            'driver' => $params->driver,
            'host' => $params->host,
            'username' => $params->username,
            'password' => $params->password
        ]]);

        return DB::connection('onthefly');
    }
}
```

And now somewhere in controller we try

use App\Helpers\DatabaseConnection;
...

```
    $params['connection_name'] = 'onthefly';
    $params['dbname'] ='dbname';
    $params['driver'] = 'mysql';
    $params['host'] = 'localhost';
    $params['username'] = 'root';
    $params['password'] = '';
    $params['port'] = 3306;

$connection = DatabaseConnection::setConnection($params);
$getTableData = $connection->table('table_name')->where("column_name",'=','matchCondition')->get();
```