# DB::Connection not updated after dynamically changing db name via Config::set in Laravel/Lumen?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm trying to connect to db dynamically through:

```
DB::disconnect('mysql');
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', 'db_1');
```

When I use `DB::table('table_from_db_1')->...`, it works perfectly. I get data from `db_1`;

However, when I try to get `DB::connection()->getDatabaseName()`, it still returns the original db name and NOT the `db_1`.

Question:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How do I efficiently test if I have actually connected to the dynamic database?

Comment: Have you tried to create a second Dataset in configuration. Check this complete example : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31847054/how-to-use-multiple-databases-in-laravel)

Comment: Not an option, I will be having 500+ dynamic databases and no code should be touched when it starts rolling.

Comment: DId you try something like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198046/laravel-change-connection-dynamically)

Comment: did you write DB::reconnect() ?

Comment: @FrédéricKlee can't do it like that since I have to change the connection entirely throughout the request lifecycle.

Comment: @DjellalMohamedAniss I did but didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem, solved the issue by using `purge` instead of `disconnect`.

```
DB::purge('mysql'); // purge instead of disconnect
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', 'db_1');
```

Finally, use `DB::connection()->getPdo();` inside `try-catch` to check if connection is valid.