# Change database connection when using Laravel Auth

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-authentication, laravel-models

In a multi-tenant Laravel app, each tenant has its own database connection. So after the user has selected his database, I want to authenticate the user using `Auth::loginUsingId`. Still, no matter what I do, I cannot change the Users Model's connection to another default.

If I set the connection in the model, it does connect to the specific database, but I want this to be done dynamically.

Is there a way to specify the connection dynamically that Laravel's auth should use for the authentication?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Change Connection Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198046/laravel-change-connection-dynamically)

Comment: @PeterKrebs This solution works on other cases, like when interacting with the users model, but it doesn't work with laravel's Auth methods.

Comment: You need to provide more specific information. How does a user selects a database? What happens after that?

Comment: When logging in the user provides his username, password and database name.

Comment: If you change the default database connection with e.g. `config([ 'database.default' => ... ])` you might need to run `DB::reconnect` after that to reset the connection

Comment: This generally works, but it doesn't work when using Laravel's Auth to login.

Answer (score 1):

You could define another connection in your `config/database.php` file like this:

```
return array(
    'connections' => array(
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'database1',
            'username'  => 'user1',
            'password'  => 'pass1'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),

        'second_db_connection' => array(
            'driver'    => 'mysql',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'database'  => 'database2',
            'username'  => 'user2',
            'password'  => 'pass2'
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
        ),
    )
```

And change the User model to be like this:

```php
class User extends Model {

    protected $connection = 'second_db_connection';
    
}
```

Comment: I already have multiple connections for each tenant. The problem is that I want to specify the connection dynamically, since there are more than two connections.

Comment: Well, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42199159/9453520

Comment: This solution works on other cases, like when interacting with the users model, but it doesn't work with  laravel's Auth methods.

Comment: See this thread: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/using-auth-on-a-different-connection-or-database

Answer (score 0):

Before authenticating the user, change the database connection temporarily for the current request only using Conifg::set

```
$db = "database_name";
Config::set("database.connections.mysql.database", $db);
```

Comment: I have already tried that and it doesn't work. It seems that it uses the default connection of the model and cannot be overwritten.
I have also tried `DB::setDefaultConnection($connection)`, but it also doesn't work...

Comment: does the other database have different username or password? if yes, then you will also have to update it using the same command. ("database.connections.mysql.username", "database.connections.mysql.password"). If not, then you will have to share the error with us from the log files.

Comment: The error is that it's trying to find the users table on the default connection database instead on the tenant's database.

Comment: Hi @HouZer did find away to get the auth to use the tenant db ??