# how to change database configs in laravel?

Tags: laravel

My larave app have setup steps.
In the database configuration step, user inputs should be placed as database configuration, but i dont know how can i set custom configs for database.

I used this code, but it changes the configs temporarily and doesn't save them.

```
Config::set("database.connections.mysql", [
    "host" => "...host...",
    "database" => "...database...",
    "username" => "...username...",
    "password" => "...password..."
]);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

Just try to change `.env` file or on `config/database.php` do your corrections

Comment: i know this, i want set this configs with form and controller !!

Comment: got this information

Comment: Try this, it must work
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198046/laravel-change-connection-dynamically